# Javascript block on AJAX load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I am looking for a way to make an AJAX load request in javascript, but have the javascript code pause execution while waiting for the AJAX load to complete. In other words, I am trying to do a *synchronous* AJAX load request (I know the 'A' in AJAX stands for asynchronous. I'm just hoping maybe the name isn't exactly right.) . What I have is

```
$('#my_id').load("my_page.pl?my_param=p1&my_other_param=p2");
//Please wait here
//Now do stuff after load is complete.
```

The reason I want the request to be synchronous is because it creates an HTML table, and then the javascript which follows parses the table.

Comment: You're using JQuery, just set the `async` variable in the AJAX object to `false`. See this link: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/, however this is not recommended as it may causes issues such a freezing the entire browser and/or memory leaks.

Comment: I'm very confident there is a better way than using a forced synchronized request anyway. Maybe explain your problem a little more in depth.

Comment: @jAndy. It's because the request will add an HTML table to the page, and then the javascript which follows parses that table.

Comment: So...Why do you need to use a synchronous request? Just make sure that the following JavaScript is not executed until the table actually exists.

Comment: Instead of inserting the table into the DOM, create an object and parse that, then insert into the DOM.

Comment: @Daniel: every jQuery *ajax method* offers *callback* possibilties. That means you can just passin a function of your own, whenever the code finished. Thats a way more convinient and Javascript-way, not blocking the browser (what will happen with synchronous requests)

Comment: @jAndy That works for me. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery's 'load()' method takes a callback. Callbacks are generally how async code handles the "waiting" feature you want.

```
$("#my_id").load("my_page.pl?my_param=p1&my_other_param=p2", function (response) {
    // do this stuff, which will run after the request is complete
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks like jquery... I can't be sure because I don't know jquery at all but if so you might get better answers tagging it as such.
I can tell you that javascript has it's own method for synchronous OR asynchronous calls. This is what I use:

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
// Use the activeX object for old IE

xmlhttp.open("GET","http://some.internet.address/woot?foo=bar", false);
// The third argument in the open function determines the asynchronous nature, 
//it was set to false, so the code will halt at the send() point while the request is executed.
xmlhttp.send();
// Now, if the call succeeded...
if (xmlhttp.status==200) {
    response = eval('('+xmlhttp.responseText+')');
    // ...save the results to an object named response...
}
else {
    // ...Otherwise do some other stuff
    errorFunction(xmlhttp.status);
}
```

Lots of good info is also available here -
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

Comment: Are you saying that the particular page I linked contains inaccurate info? Are you able to point any out on that page? I couldn't spot any myself.